# I need a workaround for assigning Liquid variables with dashes to javascript variable names

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have a short form on my product pages for customers to submit their email address. Javascript is used to assign custom properties alongside the email address in the Klaviyo email system I use to manage email subscriptions.

I have been able to use Liquid output to send some Shopify product information - such as the product ID - as one of these custom properties. However, I would like to send a SKU, handle or product name, which does not work because this data is stored using a dash as a delimiter. This causes an issue with the Javascript parser

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    KlaviyoSubscribe.attachToForms('#email_signup', {
        hide_form_on_success: true,
        custom_success_message: true,
        custom_error_message: true,
        extra_properties:{ //Fully customisable - call them what you want
            PROPERTY_{{ Shopify.Liquid.Variable }}:true
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the example above `PROPERTY_{{ product.id }}:true`
would be fine. This would resolve to something like `PROPERTY_123456789:true` which is parsed properly and transmitted.

However `PROPERTY_{{ product.handle }}:true`
would become something like `PROPERTY_product-handle-example:true`

The dashes here don't parse in javascript. I've been playing around trying to put the liquid variable into a JS string or something but not getting it. I'm sure it's simple but I can't see the wood for the trees on this one.

Comment: You can quote the key, something like this: `"PROPERTY_{{ Shopify.Liquid.Variable }}": true`.

Comment: And Lo it works. So bloody simple thank you :P

Answer (score 2):

You may use the JSON filter:

```
{{ Shopify.Liquid.Variable | json }}
```

As explained here:
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/additional-filters#json

HTH

Comment: I'm sure that would be enough for you to handle that case Josh.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess your parser really handles the page before the javascript gets send to the client, but I guess to have it correct from your point of view, you could just use `['property']`.

It should be fine from a preparser point of view

```
KlaviyoSubscribe.attachToForms('#email_signup', {
    hide_form_on_success: true,
    custom_success_message: true,
    custom_error_message: true,
    extra_properties:{ //Fully customisable - call them what you want
        ['PROPERTY_{{ Shopify.Liquid.Variable }}']:true
    }
});
```